# Saving each word in an array into a variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called $child which contains at least words. I want to loop through the array and save each word into a separate variable. Currently I tried:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $child->count();$i++)
        {
     $var1 = (string) $child[$i]->xpath;
     $var2 = (string) $child[$i+1]->xpath;
     $var3 = (string) $child[$i+2]->xpath;

}
```

This gives an error saying I'm trying to get a property of a non-object. It also isn't very generic if there's a case with more words in the array.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Sorry I've made a mistake it's not an array of word. Basically I have a SimpleXMLElement Object called $operation. SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [type] => and ) [child] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [xpath] => noNotification [assert] => exists ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [xpath] => sequence [assert] => not exists ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [xpath] => dataType/enumRef[@name = 'OperState'] [assert] => exists ) ) )

I wish to extract the noNotification, sequence and dataType/enumRef[@name = 'OperState'] from this and save them in separate variables. However I can't just aceess them directly as it must be done dynamically in case other elements are added at a later stage.

Comment: Could you show us `$child` structure? You are using it as an object but it's an array. I recommend having a look at PHP doc about [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php). Plus the code you show here can't give any error, it won't even run. (`$i  $child->count();` ? )

Comment: Sorry I've made a mistake it's not an array of word. Basically I have a SimpleXMLElement Object called $operation.                                                         SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [type] => and ) [child] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [xpath] => noNotification [assert] => exists ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [xpath] => sequence [assert] => not exists ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [xpath] => dataType/enumRef[@name = 'OperState'] [assert] => exists ) ) )

Comment: (It would be better if you edit your question with this information. ;) )

Comment: I wish to extract the noNotification, sequence and dataType/enumRef[@name = 'OperState'] from this and save them in separate variables. However I can't just aceess them directly as it must be done dynamically in case other elements are added at a later stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly there is a little character `<` missing in your code. It should be like this;

```
for($i = 0; $i < $child->count(); $i++) {
     $var1 = (string) $child[$i]->xpath;
     $var2 = (string) $child[$i+1]->xpath;
     $var3 = (string) $child[$i+2]->xpath;
}
```

**Now back to the code**

You'll experience problem with this code because you are not checking if `$child[$i+1]` actually set or not. `$i` can hit the maximum length of the `$child` and it will still try to get next 2 elements. Thus you'll end up with this error `trying to get a property of a non-object`

If you will go with this approach you should do at the very least this;

```
for($i = 0; $i < $child->count(); $i++) {
     $var1 = (string) $child[$i]->xpath;
     if (isset($child[$i+1]->xpath)) $var2 = (string) $child[$i+1]->xpath;
     if (isset($child[$i+2]->xpath)) $var3 = (string) $child[$i+2]->xpath;
}
```

To provide you further and better answer, we need to know the structure of `$child`.

One way or another looping this way is very bad practice. Consider this;

```
$child = array("test1","test2","test3","test4","test5","test6");
for($i = 0; $i < count($child); $i++){
   echo $child[$i]."<br />";
   if (isset($child[$i+1])) echo $child[$i+1]."<br />";
   if (isset($child[$i+2])) echo $child[$i+2]."<br />";
}
```

You'll end up with duplicates. Because the loop itself is going through next element and within the loop you keep going next 2 elements as well.

**Edit (after seeing the structure)**

Try this;

```
$words = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($operation->child); $i++) {
    if (isset($operation->child[$i]->xpath)) {
        $words[$i] = (string) $operation->child[$i]->xpath;
    }
}
```

Comment: How will this code solve the `trying to get a property of a non-object` error?

Comment: @caCtus you should at least read my comment before down voting maybe? I added an extra sentence to make it more clear why he might end up with this.

Comment: Which comment? I might have missed it.

Comment: @caCtus I guess you missed this part; `You'll experience problem with this code because you are not checking if $child[$i+1] actually set or not`

Anyway I later edited and added the code.

Comment: Sorry you edited after I commented, couldn't guess. `$child` being an array, I still think that this code won't work and will send the same error, no?

Comment: @caCtus It is OK. This sentence was there `You'll experience problem with this code because you are not checking if $child[$i+1] actually set or not` but later I added extra sentence + code to make it clear.

Yeah, there is also that possibility. We can't really help without knowing the structure of `$child`

Comment: OP just told it's not an array, sorry. Just removed my downvote (as always when things are clearer). :)

Answer (score -2):

There are multiple errors in your code.

First of all arrays should be parsed with [foreach](https://php.net/manual/ro/control-structures.foreach.php)

With that in mind:

```
foreach($child as $key => $value) {
    ${'word' . $key} = $value;  
}
```

Now you can make use of variables starting from $word0.

EDIT: based on your comments:

```
$myArray = array();
foreach($child as $key => $value) {
    $myArray[$key] = array(
        'xpath' => (string)$value->xpath, 
        'assert' => (string)$value-> assert,
    );
}
```

As you may have a lot of variables it's better to save data into an array as well.

try [print_r($myArray)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) after foreach to see it's contents.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the use of `for`? (Also, I don't think you mean "parsed").